# Php file executes 2 times with htaccess redirect and facebook login code

Tags: regex, facebook, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have this code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/ embed.php?video=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/ embed.php?video=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and in the embed.php I have login code (with request login, request code and state) every think works fine when user login but after user login code and state are generated twice and in error_log next error appear: `[26-Sep-2013 02:02:04 America/Chicago] CSRF state token does not match one provided.`

After I delete the code from .htaccess and run direct the file embed.php this will not run twice and CSRF error not appear anymore.

In the mebed file, I use a code what check if user allready login or not and request to login and after facebook login user is redirect back to request url.
I use this code in htaccess to create seo friendly urls like http://domain.com/videoid/title
after user login the url looks like http://domain.com/videoid/title?code=fbcode&access_token=fb_access_token

Anyone can help me to resolve this problem?

Another edit:
In Facebook developers page I put on 'Website with Facebook Login' only http :// www domainname/
And on the 'App Domains: ' I don`t enter any domain.

Many thanks,
Emil

Comment: I am a bit surprised that you do not get a redirect loop if you redirect back to the original URL from your `embed.php` file. Maybe this is what happens, but when the CSRF error appear you do not redirect?

Comment: Yes the error not appear when I delete the htaccess or delete the redirect from htaccess. When delete the htaccess and use the files embed.php?video=id , after facebook user login is redirect only once on embed.php?video=id&code=fbcode&access_token=fb_access_token and CSRF error not appear in errror_log. Maybe a problem is because I set on facebook application settings on Website with FB Login the link http:/domain.com/ and when I use htaccess redirect user is redirect to domanin,com/videoid/ and not to root domain. May this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work, if I understand your question correctly (I will use anubhavas solution as base since it's clearner), basically I do not rewrite the request if the `QUERY_STRING` contain at least one `&` since it's already been rewritten by `embed.php` itself at that point:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteOptions inherit

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &
    RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/ embed.php?video=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If needed `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &` could be a bit more specific that just `&`.

Comment: I try your solution but don`t work,after user install and allowed facebook app user remain stack in the facebook page and don`t return on call_back_url. What I was write on my question is why my page is loaded twice after user install and allowed app on facebook and after use $_GET for access_token,code and state from facebook are generated twice, this is when I use htaccess redirect when I use only embed.php?video=id, this page is not loaded twice (and code and state is not generated 2 times). When I try this solution remain in page facebook.com/app-id&permision and don`t return to my domain.